# How to print X month ago time before branch name?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clean

Below code I am trying and the output should contain the branch name with x month ago. Any suggestion in this logic would be greatly appreciated.

Here the main aim of the code is to fetch list all branch name before 4 month ago.

```
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
four_month_ago=$(( $current_timestamp - 4*30*24*60*60 ))

for x in `git branch -r`; do
    branch_timestamp=$(git show -s --format=%at $x)
    if [[ "$branch_timestamp" < "$four_month_ago" ]]; then
        list_branch+=("${x/origin\//}")
    fi
done

i=0
for x in ${list_branch[*]}; do
    printf "    %3d - %s\n" $i $x
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

**Getting Output :**

```
0 - fix-code
1 - bug-read
2 - feature/memcp-fix
```

I need to add x month time stamp after the serial number in sort by date

**Expected output :**

```
0 - 5 month ago - fix-code
1 - 7 month ago - bug-read
2 - 10 month ago - feature/memcp-fix
```

Comment: Please describe which date you want to prefix the branches with. From where do you intend to grab that date ... or how do you intend to calculate that date?

Comment: The "authordate" that need to be printed before the branch name. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: And is it the authordate of the last commit on the branch you're talking about then? The authordate of the commit the branch references?

Comment: Yes the branch creation date . Basically I have to list the 4 month old branches with serial number | branch date | branch name  and then delete all the branch listed . Please help me it would be greatly appreciated. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: You say "yes" and then you say "branch creation date", which is not the same thing. If I create a branch right now you could argue that the branch creation date is today, November 15th. However, if I work on the branch for 1 month, the actual commit the branch refers to may have an authordate of 15th of December. Can you please clarify which of those two you want? I ask because obtaining the creation date according to my example (15th of November) might not be easy depending on merges and stuff.

Comment: Let it be "committerdate" as of now . Thanks in advance for the concern and hoping for a solution @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239243/discussion-between-rowoc-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
four_month_ago=$(( $current_timestamp - 4*30*24*60*60 ))

for x in `git branch -r|sed 's/origin\///'|sed -e '/ HEAD /d'`; do
    branch_timestamp=$(git show -s --format=%at origin/$x)
    if [[ "$branch_timestamp" < "$four_month_ago" ]]; then
        num=$(( ($current_timestamp - $branch_timestamp) / (30*24*60*60)))
        list_branch+=("$num month ago - ${x}")
    fi
done

i=0
for x in "${list_branch[@]}"; do
    printf "    %3d - %s\n" $i "$x"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`git log` (and `git show`) have a `--date=<format>` option :

```
git log --date=relative --format="%ad %s" -1 <branch or commit>
```